# How can I remove a trailing double quote from a string inside an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array where some of the strings in the array have a \" at the end:

```
var splits = def.definition.Split(new string[] { @"; """ }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

splits[0] = "good string";
splits[1] = "problem string \"";
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can iterate through this array and remove the `\"` that is present in some of the rows? Is it possible to do this following on from the code I already have that gives me splits?

For reference here's the full code. Note that the \" is only a problem for everything after element [0] of the splits array:

```
var splits = def.definition.Split(new string[] { @"; """ }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
return new WebWordForm
{
    definition = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
        .ToTitleCase(splits[0].ToLower()),
    examples = splits.Skip(1).ToList(),
    partOfSpeech = definition.partOfSpeech,
    sourceId = 1,
    synonyms = def.synonyms
};
```

Here is some sample data for definition:

```
def.definition = "the trait of lacking restraint or control; " +
    "freedom from inhibition or worry; \"she danced with abandon\""

def.definition = "a feeling of extreme emotional intensity; " + 
    "\"the wildness of his anger\""

def.definition = "forsake, leave behind; " + 
    "\"We abandoned the old car in the empty parking lot\""

def.definition = "stop maintaining or insisting on; " + 
    "of ideas, claims, etc.; " + 
    "\"He abandoned the thought of asking for her " + 
    "hand in marriage\"; \"Both sides have to give up " + 
    "some calims in these negociations\""

def.definition = "give up with the intent of never claiming again; " + 
    "\"Abandon your life to God\"; \"She gave up her children to her ex"

def.definition = "leave behind empty; move out of; " + 
    "\"You must vacate your office by tonight\""
```

Comment: `; "` seems like an odd delimiter - can you add some sample data?  Maybe there's a more efficient way to do the split and handle the quotation marks at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

based on your sample data is looks like a more efficient method would be to split by using quotation marks as delimiters:

```
var splits = def.definition
                .Split(new string[] { "; ", "\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then the first element would be the definition and remaining elements would be examples.

Or just split on `"; "` and anything surrounded by quotes is an example.

---

Linq is for *querying*, not updating, so if you want to update the items in-plans then just use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<splits.Length; i++
{
    splits[i] = splits[i].Replace(@"/"","");
}
```

If you want to use Linq project the array to a *new* array (copying the times and replacing as necessary), then you can use:

```
splits = splits.Select(s => .Replace(@"\"",""))
               .ToArray();
```

which you can inline with the `Split`:

```
var splits = def.definition
                .Split(new string[] { @"; """ }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
                .Select(s => s.Replace("\"",""));
```

If you *need* the end result to be an array then you can add `ToArray()`, but  make a *copy* of the array that `Split` generates.  That may not be a problem for you overall but it is something to consider.

Comment: @D Stanley - Could this be added as part of the line in the question where I populate splits?

Comment: @D Stanley - Thanks very much. Can you maybe clarify about the array. I think from my code that I need it to be an array as the code has:  splits[0]  If you don't mind can you add this to your answer as I was a little bit confused when you said "make a copy" thank you.

Comment: @D Stanley - I added some examples.

Comment: @Marilou See my update - I think you can account for the quotation marks as part of the split process versus stripping them after the fact.

Comment: @Marilou You can use `First()` instead of `[0]` to get the first element. Then you don't need an array.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to say `splits = split.Select(s => s.Replace("\"", null)).ToArray()`

Comment: I updated the question to give a little more details. Could I add this after the line already there that creates splits?

Answer (score 0):

You could either iterate through the array itself and replace each element by using the [`TrimEnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) method or simply use LINQ to create a projection and handle the replacement that way via the [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method :

```
// Loop approach
for(var i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
{
    splits[i] = splits[i].TrimEnd('\"');
}

// LINQ projection
splits = splits.Select(s => s.TrimEnd('\"')).ToArray();
```

You can [see an example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A0PCYk).

**More Advanced Scenarios**

If you needed to handle anything more advantaged replacements, you could consider using a regular expression via the `Regex.Replace()` method, however for simple trimming, this should be sufficient :

```
// Trim off any trailing quotes or spaces
splits = splits.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s,@"[\s"]","")).ToArray();
```